# Create a function pointer from Typelist subsets

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, typelist

I have a Typelist implementation very similar to [this one](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/html/a00681.html). If you don't know what a typelist is: in short, it behaves like variadic templates using nested tuples. You can read more about them [here](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=aJ1av7UFBPwC&pg=PA64&lpg=PA64&dq=loki%20typelists&source=bl&ots=YRgG1oOi6Y&sig=kN6r9BrM2I8Se48TY7Nto3QOO-E&hl=en&sa=X&ei=vpJIUcigJLOy0AXzwYDgCw&ved=0CF8Q6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=loki%20typelists&f=false).

I would like to build up a function pointer type from a subset of this typelist. The subset is defined by a list of indexes (of any size) and the desired operation does a lookup of these indexes in the typelist and defines the type of a pointer on a function using those types as arguments.

The API would look something like:

```
#include "typelist.h"
// typelist definition
typedef Typelist<float, Typelist<double, Typelist<int, NullType>>> Pixel;

typedef FunctionFromFields<Pixel, 0, 2>::Type field_0_and_2;
// I want the definition above to be equivalent to:
// typedef void (*field_0_and_2)(float*, int*);
```

It seems reasonable to assume this is possible since everything is known at compile time, but I have yet to find the right syntax for that.

I don't want to use variadic templates to replace the typelist, however they can be used to define the pointer type.

Has anyone done something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fairly easy.  First define a `typelist_nth` type function (left as an exercise; I assume you have one in your `typelist.h`):

```
template<typename TL, int I> struct typelist_nth;
```

Then use a variadic template to build a function type:

```
template<typename TL, int... Is> struct FunctionFromFields {
    typedef void (*Type)(typename typelist_nth<TL, Is>::type *...);
};
```

Comment: Yep, that did it. It wasn't hard indeed, i just confused myself with the syntax.